# convert numpy array to list of 6 elements where each time the values should shift by one position in python

Tags: python, pandas, list, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a dataset in numpy arrays values

```
array([0.74, 0.77, 0.72, 0.65, 0.24,
       0.07,0.79,0.88])
```

I want to convert numpy array to list of 6 elements where each time the values should shift by one position in python

This is the list of list that I want to get.

```
[[0.74, 0.77, 0.72, 0.65, 0.24,0.07],[0.77, 0.72, 0.65, 0.24, 0.07,0.79],[0.72, 0.65, 0.24,
       0.07,0.79,0.88]]
```

Comment: your expected output is not clear. It is not a dataframe, but a list of lists.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem. Are you just trying to make a rolling window?

Answer (score 2):

So, it isn't clear how many times you want to shift your array, and why the length of the resulting sublists is what it is. But just use `numpy.roll`. Something to the effect of:

```
result = [np.roll(arr, -i)[:-2].tolist()  for i in range(3)]
```

Based on the comment from @hpaulj I think you want something like:

```
n = 6 # some paramter
result = [arr[i:i+n].tolist() for i in range(len(arr) - n + 1)]
```

Comment: Thanks. Its helping but i want unique number of times the list of list should generate. For example, in above list there is 8 elements, and the resulting list should be 3 with 6 values that means no roll to start values

Comment: @RajanKumarYadav what does that mean? You really must explain precisely what you are trying to do

Comment: @RajanKumarYadav **why** should the resulting list be 3 lists with 6 values in each? What is the *criteria*?

Comment: if we have 8 elements in array then i want set of 6 elements as a list with rolling of one value each time

Comment: `[arr.tolist[i:i+6] for i in range(3)]`